# a regex to prevent an text input be an email address in laravel validation php

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation, email

I need a regex for laravel validation to control my username input not be an email address
any help plz?

`<input type="text" placeholder="Don't type email address for your usename" name="username"></input>`

my Laravel validation for username input

`'username' => 'required|min:5|regex:?'`

Comment: Is `@` is a valid char for your input?

Comment: no, it is not valid for my input

Comment: So you can use this: `^[^@]{5,}$`

Comment: can you add these conditions too: 1- lower case letters. 2- at most one dot (.) in it

Comment: Try this one: `(?=^[^.]*\.?[^.]*$)[^@A-Z\s]{5,}` it also prevent space in username.

Comment: Also see this great resource on parsing emails with regexp: https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html